# Google Web Designer has a very long load time

Tags: html, banner, google-web-designer

I'm creating an html5 banner using Google Web Designer. I've created the banner and published it. When I view the published version I noticed that it takes sometime to load.

Someone else on my team is also creating HTML5 banners. The banner that he creates loads instantly even though its a larger file size. We compared our files and other than the actual assets, the way the banner was created and published is the same.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which environment are you using?
When creating a new project in GWD you are able to select an environment. By default is DoubleClick.

This adds additional file (in the case of DoubleClick, the Enabler library).
If you open your Chrome console, while running the banner, you will see that the banner is not initialized until the enabler is available.
You will also see how much time it takes to load the enabler.

If your colleague is creating a banner without that library, or without correctly listening to the event Enabler.initialized, this may be the main reason for the discrepancy.

If you don't want to include this additional library (that is used to integrate your banner in DoubleClick Studio), just select Generic from the environments dropdown.

There is also another reason that may cause the delay, and is the PoliteLoader.

You can select to politeLoad the banner from the Publish menu. 
If the PoliteLoader is selected this cause the banner to be initialized only after the page is fully loaded. This may cause delays compared to a non polite loaded ads.

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic response. My colleague and are are both using the Double Click environment. 

I did what you suggested, and I see that the banner is not initialized until the enabler is available. For mine it takes 1.008s, my colleagues takes 0.015s. 

So does this mean that my banner is correct, and this initial load time is the way it is and we can't fix it? Or is there a way to get access to the enabler faster?

Comment: Also we need it to be in the Double Click environment since we're going to be running our ads using Double Click

Comment: So, the usual loading time of the enabler may varies between 200ms and 2seconds.  It does surprise me that your colleagues' ad starts in only 0.015s.  I'd expect they are not listening to the initialized event correctly. Or they are pointing to a local version of the enabler and not the CDN version (the one hosted by Doubleclick). Your colleagues' banner may work correctly, but I highly recommend to follow step by step what is stated in this guide:  https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2672553?hl=en

Comment: Please consider to flag the answer as correct if it does address your problem and/or up the comment.

Answer (score 7):

GWD add this code at the end of the banner and animation show up immediately:

```
<script data-exports-type="dclk-quick-preview">studio.Enabler.setRushSimulatedLocalEvents(true);</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This all seems not to be a bug, but a feature of enabler.js simulates a test environment, when not beeing uploaded to Adwords (guess it similar in Doubleclick). Uploading to Google Environments should change the situation

Look at the console and see:

1. There is a long delay in alle items loading after the enabler.js.
2. It is NOT because of a long loading time of enabler.js - thats all fine.
3. Looking at the Logs, the enabler waits a second and throws out:

[  1.008s] [studio.sdk] Using default ad parameters in test environment. Simulating local events.

When uploading to Google Adwords (i assume that this all is similar to DC Studio) - the enabler throws out different logs and the delay disappears.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Realy helpful. Thx. The next question is : Is there a way to force an environment if we are not using Google Adword but local storage or something like revive?

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467738/1478067) by @Ollatair

Answer (score 0):

By chance, I found out a way to make the Enabler loading fast. Instead of using Publish, use Preview to generate the HTML.

For some reasons, Enabler.js in preview-generated HTML only takes 0.019s to load as compared to Enabler.js in publish-generated HTML taking 1.015s to load.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. We've moved away from using Google Web Designer as our animation tool. We're currently using Hype 3. If we decide to go back to Google Web Designer we'll make sure to keep this suggestion in mind. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Studio Enabler SDK looks for "e" parameter in iframe URL containing Studio creative.  It expects a number and uses that to set the creative environment.

Setting `e=1` in your preview environment (query string parameter in the iframe url pointing at the index.html for your studio creative) will tell Enabler to use LIVE mode.

I assume there is a reason why Enabler has this functionality (avoid counting impressions or paying for impressions from test/qa environment)...so I wouldn't suggest using this as a permanent setting.